# JSF 1.2 Radio Button ValueChangeListener Value not saved

Tags: java, jsf-1.2, valuechangelistener

I have a little problem with a ValueChangeListener of a radio button here.
I use Apache Tomcat 7.0 with JSF 1.2.

*t tomahawk

```
<t:selectOneRadio id="testRadio" onchange="submit()" value="#{testBean.radioItem}">
  <f:selectItems value="#{testBean.radioItems}" />
  <f:valueChangeListener type="packe.path.testBean" />
</t:selectOneRadio>
```

And my bean:

```
public class testBean implements ValueChangeListener, ActionListener, Serializable {

  // ...

  @Override
  public void processValueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
    this.data.clear();
    this.ceil = false; // ceil belongs to a checkbox
  }
}
```

Okay, the problem: If I change the radio button's value, I want my ValueChangeListener to be fired. In the listener I want to set another property (ceil) in the bean to false so my checkbox gets unchecked.
In debug mode I have checked if the radio button's listener is fired. It is.

The problem I have now is that if I reload the page then the checkbox has the same value like it has been before - but I set it to false in the listener?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with the *scope* of your **testBean**. If you didn't explicitly assign then by default it's *Stateless*. When you reload the page, you create another testBean object so the previous value for **radioItem** variable is not there anymore. Change the scope to *SESSION* might be able to help you keep the checkbox status until you log out.

Comment: My bean already is session scoped. Btw I think it has to do something with the application life cycle but I don't know what to change.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this works:

```
context.renderResponse();

ViewHandler handler = context.getApplication().getViewHandler();
String viewId = context.getViewRoot().getViewId();
UIViewRoot root = handler.createView(context, viewId);

root.setViewId(viewId);
context.setViewRoot(root);
```